# Centralização de ul de forma estranha

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Estou com um problema muito estranho.

css

```css
.lista {
 margin:0 auto;
}

ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
}

ul.listaTopo {
 background-color:#000;
 color:#FFF;
}

ul.listaTopo li, ul.listaRegistros li {
    display:inline-block;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista" style="width:900px">
  <ul class="listaTopo">
    <li style="width:100px">TIPO 
    <li style="width:400px">NOME 
    <li style="width:100px">LOGIN 
    <li style="width:100px">BLOQUEIO 
    <li style="width:100px">EDITAR 
    <li style="width:100px">EXCLUIR 
  </ul>
  <ul class="listaRegistros">
    <li style="text-align:left; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF">Super
    <li style="text-align:left; width:400px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF">Carlos Rocha
    <li style="text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF">caca
    <li style="text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF"><a href="" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este Administrador?')" '=""><img src="_img/bloquear.png" height="30px" title="Bloquear Administrador"></a>
    <li style="text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF"><a href="administradoresEditar.php?acao=form&amp;idAdmin=1"><img src="_img/editar.png" height="30px" title="Editar Administrador"></a>
    <li style="text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF"><a href="" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este Administrador?')" '=""><img src="_img/excluir.png" height="30px" title="Excluir Administrador"></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Tenho a div. lista e estou setando margin dela como `0 auto` no css mas não esta funcionando.

Mas se faço:

```
 $(".lista").css('margin', '0 auto');
```

Com JQuery funciona.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

talvez, tente colocar um display block na div: ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros

margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;

Comment: Já respondi. Era falta de atenção minha. Desculpe e obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Desculpa gente. Talvez a solução possa ajudar alguém no futuro.

Fiz um comentário estilo php

```
////////////////////////// INICIO LISTAGENS //////////////////
////////////////////////// FIM LISTAGENS /////////////////////
```

Mas tem que ter o curinga

```
/*                           INICIO LISTAGENS                 */
/*                            FIM LISTAGENS                   */
```